# Application opens multiple connections w/ Oracle DB server and query times out

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I hope I'm giving enough detail for an answer. I've got a very strange problem plaguing one of my ASP.NET applications. Without posting the actual code (and given the nature of the issue I don't even think it's necessary) the application takes inputs from a textbox, adds to a SQL string, queries an Oracle DB server and returns the results to a datatable. I have users in multiple geographic locations and this issue only happens to users in my specific location; users in Europe or Asia cannot reproduce the error. Here is how the issues manifests itself: the application queries the DB server, runs for about a minute w/o returning the results and then opens 4 more connections to the DB server. It continues to run until the page times out and leaves all of the connections open. If I try to run the application in localhost to try to figure out what is happening I can't reproduce it, it only happens when running the application off of the webserver from my location. Happy to post the code if necessary but given that it only happens under certain circumstances I don't think that the code itself is the issue. Any thoughts/experiences with similar issues?

Comment: "I don't think that the code itself is the issue"... not sure what else you think it might be.  You might get more help if you post some code.  Is this consistent for all users in your area?  What are the queries being run by the active/open connections?  Sure no SQL injection?

Comment: The code is the same for all users. If there was an issue with the code then all users should experience the issue, no? The queries being run a fairly basic select queries with joins & filters but again every user runs the same query.

Comment: You might need to build some debugging into the app - write a log line for every connection and ascertain whether the web code is being called multiple times or whether it's something to do with the driver.

Comment: If you have, for example, a SQL injection vulnerability (a code issue), then the problem would only show itself when a malicious user tries to exploit it.  But again, we can only guess because we have nothing to go by (no code to check).  Not trying to be difficult, just saying...the part about taking the user input from a textbox threw a red flag to me, but I can only guess